# How to create a new directory with Browserify if it does not exist?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I tried to save a compiled js bundle file to a production directory with Browserify and Gulp.
But it seems that Browserify can't find the valid path to the output directory.
Below is the code snippet:

```js
  browserify({ debug: true })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
      presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }))
    .require('./client/client.js', { entry: true })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.timeEnd();
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/bundle.js'));
```

And I am getting the following error:

```js
[19:37:57] Finished 'lint' after 14 s
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1148:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.saveFile [as _transform]
```

I tried to use the manual way by:

```js
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/dist/public/bundle.js`));
```

And it doesn't work.
But below works:

```js
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/dist/bundle.js`));
```

Here folder 'dist' exists in the directory but not 'public' in the 'dist'.
I think this is the reason, but how can I resolve it to save the bundle file to 'dist/public'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two attempts fail for different reasons.

Your first attempt using `gulp.dest()` fails because `browserify()` returns a simple character stream, whereas `gulp.dest()` can only work on streams of [`vinyl`](http://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) objects. You need to use the [`vinyl-source-stream`](http://npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) module to convert the char stream to a `vinyl` stream. After that `gulp.dest()` will work and will create any folders that don't exist yet:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

browserify({ debug: true })
  .transform(babelify.configure({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
  }))
  .require('./client/client.js', { entry: true })
  .bundle()
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.timeEnd();
  })
  .pipe(source('bundle.js')) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/'));
```

Your second attempt only uses char streams, but fails because [`fs.createWriteStream()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) can only create the `bundle.js` file itself, not any of the necessary parent directories. You'll have to do that manually beforehand. I suggest the [`mkdirp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) module which recursively creates directory structures of arbitrary depth if they don't exist:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var fs = require('fs');

mkdirp('dist/public/', function(err) {
  if (err) { /* handle error somehow */ }

  browserify({ debug: true })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
      presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }))
    .require('./client/client.js', { entry: true })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.timeEnd();
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('dist/public/bundle.js'));
});
```

Which one of these two solutions you choose is up to you, but if this is code that you're running from a gulpfile then I suggest you use the first one.